# rsync isn't understanding what is the relative part in --files-from=FILE

Tags: rsync

I've a file that looks like this:

```
/cygdrive/d/path/to/my/file1.png
/cygdrive/d/path/to/my/file2.png
/cygdrive/d/path/to/my/file3.png
/cygdrive/d/path/to/my/file4.png
```

I'm calling rsync with:

```
rsync --files-from="/cygdrive/d/myfiles.txt" "/cygdrive/d/path/to/" "user@remotehost:/cygdrive/c/new/path/for"
```

I want rsync to make dir structure like:

```
c:\new\path\for\my\file1.png
...
```

But it's failing with errors like:

> rsync: change_dir "/cygdrive/c/new/path/for/cygdrive/d/path/to/my" failed: No such file or directory
>   rsync: mkstmp "/cygdrive/c/new/path/for/cygdrive/d/path/to/my/file1.png.asdjfhsdj" failed: No such file or directory

How do I make rsync understand that `/cygdrive/d/path/to/` is the part of the source path that is the "root" and that only subfolders/files of it should be replicated to the destination root to give a new path at the destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the bit specified on the command line is the "source root" part and the line from the file is the "relative" part.

Hence I needed to strip `/cygdrive/d/path/to/` out of all the lines in the file leaving just `my/file1.png`

Then when called with the command line from the question, rsync assembled the local file path using the `cmd_line_source + file_line`, and copied it to `cmd_line_dest + file_line`